# Why not show facebook share dialog on mobile?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile

Why not show facebook share dialog on mobile ?

this is my code

```
<a href="https://web.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D&p%5Bsummary%5D&p%5Burl%5D=http://stackoverflow.com/&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D&_rdr">test</a>
```

when test on desktop it's show like this.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ok4tJWk.png]

it's ok ^_^

But when i test on my mobile it's show like this.

[image]

Then i tried to press `Preview` button it's will show like this

[image]

it's still show loading T_T

Why my facebook share not work on mobile , how can i do ?